# caching views based on arguments as taxonomy term id

Tags: caching

Hi need to enable caching based on taxonomy term id from the url which the views takes as an argument

1)simple cache returns empty results

2)views_arg_cache module also empty

3)views_content_cache module aslo empty

please help if any body has tried such scenario and found the solution

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/cache_actions might help you out.

Cache actions provides rules actions for clearing drupal caches.

It currently provides actions for:

> Clearing Drupal cache bins
>   Clearing CSS/JS cache
>   Clearing The cache of specific views
>   Clearing The cache of specific panel pages
>   Clearing The cache of specific mini panels

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by choose Granularity -> Arguments

Comment: tell me how you solved this problem?

Comment: when u choose caching you will find 2 labels
1- Lifetime 
2- Granularity
note from (it comes from Content -> Display settings link the top left corner )

then choose from the select list -> Granularity ->Arguments

Comment: is this a D6 option?

Comment: I made it for D7 version and didn't try D6